# using images in next/previous_post_link

Tags: php, array, next-post-link, previous-post-link

In my blog's pagination section, I've used `<?php previous_post_link(); ?>` and `<?php next_post_link(); ?>` to generate the newer and older posts links. Within that action, though, I've included an empty span that I insert an image in with CSS. While no errors have been generated by the code, the images don't show up. I'm wondering why this is, and if there is an easier/better what to achieve the desired effect?

```
<div class="pagination">    
        <ul>
            <li><?php previous_post_link('<span class="left-arrow"></span> older posts'); ?></li>
            <li><?php next_post_link('<span class="right-arrow"></span> newer posts'); ?></li>
        </ul>            
    </div><!-- end pagination -->

#blog .pagination {
    background: url('img/dots_large.png') no-repeat;
    height: 169px;
    width: 635px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#blog .pagination ul { 
    display:inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#blog .pagination ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 290px;
}

#blog .pagination .left-arrow {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#blog .pagination .right-arrow {
    padding-left: 20px;
}


#blog .pagination span.left-arrow {
    background: url('arrow_left.png') no-repeat;
}

#blog .pagination span.right-arrow {
    background: url('arrow_right.png') no-repeat;
}
```

[live site](http://blog.christaandivy.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of image  is incorrect.

Change

```
#blog .pagination span.left-arrow {
    background: url('arrow_left.png') no-repeat;
}

#blog .pagination span.right-arrow {
    background: url('arrow_right.png') no-repeat;
}
```

to

```
#blog .pagination span.left-arrow {
    background: url('img/arrow_left.png') no-repeat;
}

#blog .pagination span.right-arrow {
    background: url('img/arrow_right.png') no-repeat;
}
```